# UIPresentationController preferredContentSize update animated

Tags: ios, animation, uikit, uipresentationcontroller

So I have a very basic UIPresentationController that basically display contentView centered on screen, it's size is determined by view controller preferredContentSize. (Its very much similar to regular modal view controller presented as FormSheet).

What I'm trying to achieve, is to be able to update size of this view controllers' view dynamically, by just changing it's preferredContentSize.

When I set preferredContentSize, my subclass of UIPresentationController receive information about it in:

```
-(void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
```

But how can I from here resize the view frame with animation ? If I just call:

```
-(void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.presentedView.frame = [self frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView];
    } completion:nil]; 
}
```

Immediately gets called containerViewWillLayoutSubviews and frame is changed without animation.

```
-(void)containerViewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    self.presentedView.frame = [self frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView];
}
```

Please help me find a way, to resize it with animation. It must be possible, since it resizes with animation for example when rotation happens.

Comment: Do you fix this without using some weird `isAnimating` flag in `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the frame from within `preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer`, you only need to call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` on the container view.
This causes `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` to be invoked, which will update the frame using your animation configuration.

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.containerView setNeedsLayout];
        [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil]; 
}
```

**Swift:**

```
override func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer) {
    super.preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer: container)
    
    guard let containerView = containerView else {
        return
    }
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        containerView.setNeedsLayout()
        containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

### Alternative approach

Alternatively you could not have the animate block in `preferredContentSizeDidChange...`, and instead place the assignment of `preferredContentSize` in an animate block.

This way you have more control over the animation speed of individual transitions.

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
{
    [self.containerView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
}

// In view controller:

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width, 500.f);
}];
```

**Swift:**

```
override func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer) {
    super.preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer: container)
    
    guard let containerView = containerView else {
        return
    }
    
    containerView.setNeedsLayout()
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
}

// In view controller

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.width, height: 500)
}
```

Comment: "In view controller" this represents which scope?

Comment: The view controller you're presenting. So for for example; update the height of the presented view controller when someone is scrolling in it.

Comment: what is containerView? getting error `Cannot find 'containerView' in scope`

Comment: Just a note. One needs to override containerViewWillLayoutSubviews to make this work. Also look at my answer about using sheetPresentationController's detents.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use auto layout. Make an outlet from your containers height constraint:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *drawerViewHeightConstraint;
```

then add the following code:

```
- (void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
{
    [super preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:container];
    self.drawerViewHeightConstraint.constant = container.preferredContentSize.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                       [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: While this might work, it's not necessary to use auto layout, as you imply.

Answer (score -3):

This is not a direct answer to a question but there is another approach to create a resizable sheet, than manually changing a `preferredContentSize`.

In **iOS 15**, there is a public API to present a resizable bottom sheet (or centered sheet on iPad).

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet

    if let sheet = viewController.sheetPresentationController {
        sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
    }

    rootViewController.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now user can make this `viewController` bigger or smaller by just panning it.

This works on `iPad` as well.